# Even after installing curses(pip install windows-curses) i am getting the error (curses function returned NULL)

Tags: python-3.x, python-curses

```
import curses
from curses import KEY_RIGHT, KEY_LEFT, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN
from random import randint


curses.initscr()
win = curses.newwin(20, 60, 0, 0)
win.keypad(1)
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
win.border(0)
win.nodelay(1)
```

this is the error i am getting

win = curses.newwin(20, 60, 10, 10)
_curses.error: curses function returned NULL

Answer (score 1):

You might have to switch editors to like [repl.it](https://repl.it) or you'll have to make an IDLE file and run that in the terminal.